# Can I specify the display position of overflow content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First off I am totally open to edits to my title and / or tags.  I am not clear how to describe this question.

I have a tab interface that collapses to a overflow div in mobile mode (like GitHub does).  Looks like this:

[image]

The issue I have is the active tab is hidden - I want the active one to always be displayed by default vs the user needing to 'slide' it over to find it:

[image]

I have zero idea where to start.  Is this CSS, Anchors (not ideal), Javascript?

Comment: To alert the user that tab is active simply change the color of the text. I'm sure if the tab is active, it must have an active class?

Comment: I probably wasn’t clear. The second image is the same div just ‘slid’ over. The history is the current active one. It’s just hidden by default because the div renders with the left side first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a ref  or some identifier to the active tab and always scroll to that tab on page reload or mount.

Something like this maybe or your own logic,

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: That seems like what I am looking for. I can easily add an id to that active tab and give this a shot. I have this across my site so this seems a quick and easy way to implement this.  I will give this a shot and report back.

Comment: So close... works fine in the console but when I add this to my Rails JS manifest the div only scrolls over half way.  Very weird.  No errors etc.

Comment: Must be my code but adding a setTimeout (with time to 0) fixes it (for now).